# Threading cost - minimum execution time when threads would add speed

Tags: c#, performance, multithreading

I am working on a C# application that works with an array. It walks through it (meaning that at one time only a narrow part of the array is used). I am considering adding threads in it to make it perform faster (it runs on a dualcore computer). The problem is that I do not know if it would actually help, because threads cost something and this cost could easily be more than the parallel gain... So how do I determine if threading would help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try writing some benchmarks that mimic, as closely as possible, the real-world conditions in which your software will actually be used.

Test and time the single-threaded version. Test and time the multi-threaded version. Compare the two sets of results.

Answer (score 4):

If your application is CPU bound (i.e. it isn't spending time trying to read files or waiting for data from a device) and there is little to no sharing of live data (data being altered, if its read only its fine) between the threads then you can pretty much increase the speed by 50->75% by adding another thread (as long as it still remains CPU bound of course).

The main overhead in multithreading comes from 2 places.

1. Creation & initialization of the thread. Creating a thread requires quite a few resources to be allocated and involves swaps between kernel and user mode, this is expensive though a once off per thread so you can pretty much ignore it if the thread is running for any reasonable amount of time. The best way to mitigate this problem is to use a thread pool as it will keep the thread on hand and not need to be recreated.
2. Handling synchronization of data. If one thread is reading from data that another is writing, bad things will generally happen (worse if both are changing it). This requires you to lock your data before altering it so that no thread reads a half written value. These locks are generally quite slow as well. To mitigate this problem, you need to design your data layout so that the threads don't need to read or write to the same data as much as possible. If you do need a lot of these locks it can then become slower than the single thread option.

In short, if you are doing something that requires the CPU's to share a lot of data, then multi-threading it will be slower and if the program isn't CPU bound there will be little or no difference (could be a lot slower depending on what it is bound to, e.g. a cd/hard drive). If your program matches these conditions, then it will PROBABLY be worthwhile to add another thread (though the only way to be certain would be profiling).

One more little note, you should only create as many CPU bound threads as you have physical cores (threads that idle most of the time, such as a GUI message pump thread, can be ignored for this condition).

P.S. You can reduce the cost of locking data by using a methodology called "lock-free programming", though this something that should really only be attempted by people with a lot of experience with multi-threading and a clear understanding of their target architecture (including how the cache is treated and the memory bus).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [Luke's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453378/threading-cost-minimum-execution-time-when-threads-would-add-speed/2453401#2453401). Benchmark it, it's the only way to be sure.

I can also give a prediction of the results - the fastest version will be when the number of threads matches the number of cores, EXCEPT if the array is very small and each thread would have to process just a few items, the setup/teardown times might get larger than the processing itself. How few - that depends on what you do. Again - benchmark.

I'd advise to find out a "minimum number of items for a thread to be useful". Then, when you are deciding how many threads to spawn (or take from a pool), check how many cores the computer has and how many items there are. Spawn as many threads as possible, but no more than the computer has cores, and not so many that each thread would have less than the minimum number of items to process.

For example if the minimum number of items is, say, 1000; and the computer has 4 cores; and your list contains 2500 items, you would spawn just 2 threads, because more threads would be inefficient (each would process less than 1000 items).

Answer (score 1):

Making a step by step list for Luke's idea:

1. Make a single threaded test app
2. Download Sysinternals [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) and run it
3. Run your test app and find it on the process list (remember to run it as a release build outside of Visual Studio)
4. Double click the process and select the *Performance Graph* tab
5. Observe the CPU time used by your process
6. If the CPU time is sittling flat 50% for more than a few seconds, you can probably speed your overall process up using threads (assuming the bunch of stuff Mr Peters refered to holds true)

(However, the best you can do on a duel core machine is to halve the time it takes to run. If your process only take 4 seconds, it might not be worth getting it to run in 2 seconds)

Using the [task parallel library / Rx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx) provides a friendlier interface than System.Threading.ThreadPool, which might make your world a bit easier.

Answer (score 0):

You miss imho one item, which is that it is not always about execution time. There is:

- The problem to koop a UI operational during an operation. Even if the UI is "dormant", a nonresponsive message pump makes a worse impression.
- The possibility to use a thread pool to actually not ahve to start / stop threads all the time. I use thread pools very extensively, and various parts of the applications keep them busy.

Anyhow, ignoring my point 1 - where you may go multi threaded without speeding things up in order to keep your UI responsive - I would say it is always then faster when you can actually either split up work (so you can keep more than one core busy) or offload it for othe reasons.

Comment: It already uses multithreading for IO operations and to keep UI responsive, the question was when the core computation should be multithreaded.

Comment: When it make sense. When you can cut down significantly on perceived user time - I would NOT bother for anything that takes less than 0.25 seconds to start with (users dont notice). But after that, if I can use 3-4 cores I may do so ;)